# System.exit() failed on Javascript build, any preprocessor for this?

Tags: codenameone

My codenameone apps work on android/desktop, but when I tried to send as javascript build, it show

```
    ...
    [INFO] Building JavaScript file
    [INFO] JavaScript file built with errors
    [ERROR] Method java.lang.System.exit(I)V was not found
        at userclasses.StateMachine$29.actionPerformed(StateMachine.java:2637)
        at com.codename1.impl.html5.HTML5Implementation$3$1.run(HTML5Implementation.java:369)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.callSerially(Display.java:768)
        at com.codename1.impl.html5.Stub.main(Stub.java:66)
    ...
```

It seems failed on line System.exit(). I need this in android build, do codenameone have any "preprocessor" for me to comment/uncomment some codes when sending for different build, for easier code maintenance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Display.getInstance().exitApplication()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#exitApplication--) instead.